# how to access parameter send by iOS as parameter

Tags: php, ios

i am send data from iOS side API like

```
    {
    "broker_name" : " test 2",
    "concession" : 2,
    "doller_rate" : 70,
    "due_day" : 30,
    "party_name" : "Test",
    "payment_amount" : "274.4",
    "payment_date" : "02 May 2016",
    "rate" : 0,
    "sale_date" : "02 April 2016",
    "serial_number" : "Test 1",
    "transection_type" : 1,
    "user_id" : 2,
    "weight" : [{
            "carat_rate" : 2,
            "carat_weight" : 2,
            "sub_serial_Note" : "d",
            "total" : "4.0",
         },
         {
            "carat_rate" : 4,
            "carat_weight" : 4,
            "sub_serial_Note" : "k",
            "total" : "16.0"
        }]
}
```

How to access this parameter in PHP and access right array with dictionary.

Comment: why dont you send JSON instead? Then you can use `json_decode`

Comment: @Gordon it is json in iphone

Answer (score -1):

You want to get that json in on varible

```
$json_get = $_REQUEST['yoursenddata'];
```

Then decode this data to array

```
$json_array=json_decode($json);
print_r($json_array);
$broker = $json_array['broker_name'];
```

Same for others.

Comment: i want to access weight , i get all there parameter but i can't access weight.

Comment: The shown data is not json, so json_decode will not decode it